# Magento 2 payment method based on customer group

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, customer-group

How to do Magento 2 payment method based on customer group in frontend checkout page .

Iam checking condition for Remaining Amount

But i want customer group also , if

Customer group=4 then only its should display

```
if($creditdata->getRemainingAmount()<$paymentamount)

      return false;

        else

            return true;


Thanks in advance.

This is my code ....


<?php


namespace Ced\CreditLimit\Model;

class CreditPaymentHide extends \Ced\CreditLimit\Model\CreditPayment

{


    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)

    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $checkoutdata = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if(!$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('b2bextension/credit_limit/enable')){
        return false;
      }
      if($customer->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $creditdata = $objectManager->create('Ced\CreditLimit\Model\CreditLimit')->load($customer->getCustomerId(),'customer_id');


        $discountTotal =0;
            foreach ($checkoutdata->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item){
                $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
            }
            $total = $checkoutdata->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal();
            $paymentamount = $total-$discountTotal;
            if($creditdata->getRemainingAmount()<$paymentamount)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post some code you've done or some research for the same

Comment: describe your requirement in detail. Do you want this in custom payment method? Or you are asking something else?

Comment: i have update code please have a ckeck  MR.Vivek and MR.Dhiren.....

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module and use event "payment_method_is_active" to fire an observer.

```
    <?php
    namespace YourNamespace\DisabledPgByCustomergroup\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class ObserverforDisabledPaymentgateway implements ObserverInterface
    {
      public function __construct() {}

      /**
       *
       * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
       * @return void
       */
      public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if(
          $quote !== null && 
          $quote->getCustomerGroupId() =='FOO_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID'
        ){
            /* Disable FOO payment gateway */
            if($method_instance->getCode() == 'FOO_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE'){
                 $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
      }
    }
```